# Error While calling service from activity

Tags: android

below is the code I use to call a service from my activity.
I want to call the service when the progress bar reaches its max value. what would be the right way to do it? as my progress bar reached to max then i got error....

```
    Handler progressHandler = new Handler()
    {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
            if (dialog.getProgress() == dialog.getMax())
            {

                //Log.d(TAG, "onClick: stopping srvice");

                // stopService(new Intent(oddg.this, MyService.class));

                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
                startService(new Intent(oddg.this, MyService.class)); 
            }

            dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);
        }
    };
```

Logs:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service org.androidpeople.dialog.MyService: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: 
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
```

Comment: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(725): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service org.androidpeople.dialog.MyService: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.               This is error i got in log file......

Answer (score 2):

When you call any intent from a service you have set flag as you have mentioned in your error log:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, "next activity.class");  //mContext is a Context variable.
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You give : this.startService(intent);

Comment: i want to call  MyService class thats y i have written there...is that wrong????please tell me

Comment: can u please try giving "Activity name".this.startService(new Intent(oddg.this, MyService.class));

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this:
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));